# Using Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) interface in kernel module

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, driver, pwm

I'm new in kernel development driver and I'm trying to develop a Linux kernel module, using the this module information:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pwm/pwm-tiehrpwm.c

But I didn't understand how to use it. How could adapt this module or better, how to create a new module using functions contained in this file like ehrpwm_pwm_config, ehrpwm_pwm_enable?

PS:I don't want to use sysfs, I would configure the pwm signal programmatically. I'm using a Beaglebone Black board running a Debian distribution , and cape-universaln.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `CONFIG_PWM_TIEHRPWM` in your `.config` file of your linux-kernel. By default, `CONFIG_PWM_TIEHRPWM is not set` and you need to enable it as `CONFIG_PWM_TIEHRPWM=y`, if you want to build it as a part of kernel image, or as `CONFIG_PWM_TIEHRPWM=m`, if you want to build it as a `LKM`.

Then, build your kernel as `make -j12` and `insmod` your module as:

`#insmod /lib/modules/$uname -r/drivers/pwm/pwm_tiehrpwm.ko` if you have built it as a `LKM`. Check `Linux kernel documentation` on how to configure `pwm`!

Comment: @sachinmokashi.I had already done this step. This module is loaded with success in kernel. My doudt is how could I use it? I check the Linux documentation, but it isn't clearly explained. I don't know how to instantiate it in another module and to use the functions defined there. Do you have some tip for?

Comment: You need to use EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL() macro to use the functions in another module. I would suggest you read [link](http://free-electrons.com/doc/books/ldd3.pdf) Chapter 2 for better understanding of linux kernel programming

Comment: So I need to recompile this module to include the EXPORT_SYMBOL for each function that I want to use. What does this structure mean?
static const struct pwm_ops ehrpwm_pwm_ops = {...} at line 417 of the file
How does this structure work? I had thought that is possible to call this functions through its.

Comment: @SachinMokashi, no, there is a public in-kernel API to use PWMs.